# Is regular Java the same as the Java for Android

Tags: java, android

Is regular Java the same as the Java for Android?

If yes - from where can I download a good java reference?

Looking for something like:  `Command   |   small sample   |   short Explanation`

Comment: Java is Java, but the libraries are probably different.  Android is certainly a subset of Java SE with additions of its own.  Not possible to give you a succinct answer.  Dig in and start researching.

Comment: See [this](http://www.zdnet.com/blog/burnette/java-vs-android-apis/504) and [this](http://forum.openhandsetdevelopers.com/android-versus-java-apis-t18.html)

Answer (score 6):

Yes it is. The syntax is exactly the same and you can use the same methods that are available in Java SE. Android has its own SDK (Software Development Kit) which is specific Java classes and methods for Android, i.e. dealing with click events and user interface.

However, although Java and Android Java is the same, certain libraries you add for extra functionality may or may not work. I.e. the MySQL Connection library if you try and import that for use with Android it will display an error and your android app will not compile until the MySQL library is removed from the project.

Hope this makes sense to you

Answer (score 1):

> Is regular Java the same as the Java for Android?

Yes it is. With a few tweaks.

http://developer.android.com/reference/

Answer (score 1):

Java lanaguage is basically the same for android. I think its the api's that are modified a bit to work with the dalvik vm.

Dalvik, optimized for embedded execution, and one that has its own binary format (Dalvik Executable), and does not use the Java bytecode format.

Java classes on android are based on Apache Harmony. (Wikipedia and some other forums.)

Yo should read this [post](http://www.artima.com/forums/flat.jsp?forum=276&thread=218986) Has some information that I've heard for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

Java Coding and the Syntax is the same. But the SDK is very different from regular Java JDK. The "only" thing you need to do is download Android SDK install the plugin in Eclipse and know how to use the SDK. There are tons of books that introduces you to the Android SDK.